# Is there a way to test an OptionSet with a switch statement?

Tags: swift

Defining a simple OptionSet:

```
public struct TestSet : OptionSet, Hashable
{
    public let rawValue: Int
    public init(rawValue:Int){ self.rawValue = rawValue}
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return self.rawValue
    }

    public static let A   = TestSet(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    public static let B   = TestSet(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    public static let C   = TestSet(rawValue: 1 << 2)
}
```

Call it:

```
let ostest : TestSet = [.A, .B]

switch ostest{
case .A: print("A")
case .B: print("B")
case .C: print("C")
default: print("Default")
}

if ostest.contains(.A){
    print("Contains A")
}
if ostest.contains(.B){
    print("Contains B")
}
```

Output is:

```
Default
Contains A
Contains B
```

Is there a way to check if OptionSets contain a value or combination of values with a switch statement? It would be much cleaner than a series of if-contains statements.

Comment: The whole shtick of a `switch` statement is that it picks one of a series of cases. You can't have it call both the `.A` cause and the `.B` case, because that's not the kind of mutual exclusion a `switch` offers

Comment: You can use the `case let value where value.contains(.A):` syntax, but you cannot fallthrough, somewhat defeating the purpose of the `OptionSet`.

Comment: The issue becomes how do you act on the matches? Do you provide a mapping of option to action? Do you get a `Set` or `Array` of matches? With `switch` there is a one-to-one mapping of match to action, with what you are asking it's many-to-many.

Comment: Does anybody have advice on how to do something switch-like with an option set that isn't as ugly as a mess of if / else statements? In my case, I have say 6 bits that describe a type this object is, then there's several bits that describe whether or not this object has reached a certain state. I would generally only be testing on set of those bits at a time. I'd prefer not to have to separate this into multiple option sets, I like that the current one can describe the entirety of the object's state. But if any of the state bits are set, I can't do a switch case on the type bits.

Comment: @JakeT. I've suggested something fairly extensible in the answer to this question. I would appreciate your thoughts on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly because switch is using Equatable and, I think, is using SetAlgebra.

However, you can wrap the OptionSet with something like:

```
public struct TestSetEquatable<T: OptionSet>: Equatable {

    let optionSet: T

    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {

        return lhs.optionSet.isSuperset(of: rhs.optionSet)
    }
}
```

Which lets you do:

```
let ostest : TestSet = [.A, .C]

switch TestSetEquatable(optionSet: ostest) {

  case TestSetEquatable(optionSet: [.A, .B]):
   print("-AB")
   fallthrough

 case TestSetEquatable(optionSet: [.A, .C]):
   print("-AC")
   fallthrough

 case TestSetEquatable(optionSet: [.A]):
   print("-A")
   fallthrough

   default:
     print("-")
}
```

This prints:

```
-AC
-A
- // from the fall through to default
```

Opinion: I'm not inclined to do use this code myself but if I had to, this is what I would do.